# It is possible to use SharedPreferences to set Newgame and Continue to latest activity

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

i have a question here that is possible to make sharedpreference set Newgame and Continue to latest activity?
i had 4 activity, menu.class, levelone.class, leveltwo.class, levelthree.class

i will explain with my `menu.class` code

```
public class menu extends Activity {


    public static final String PREF_LEVEL = "Level";
    public static final String PREF_IS_SET ="isSet";
    public static final String PREF_LIFES = "Lifes";

    int level;

    Button newgame, continues, continuelocked;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.menu);                 


        SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("SavedGame", MODE_PRIVATE); 

        // Check wether the pref is set or not.
        if (pref.getBoolean(PREF_IS_SET, false)) {
            // The prefs is set. Do some game logic here. Like checking for level.
            if (pref.getInt(PREF_LEVEL,0) == 0) {
                // Reset the level
                resetPrefs(pref); 
            }
            else { 
                //Do nothing at all.
            }
        }
        else {
            // if it's not set, just create it.
            resetPrefs(pref);
        }

        //i got error on this newgame line   
    newgame=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonnewgame);
    newgame.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){

            pref.putInt(PREF_LEVEL,0);    
        }             
      });
    }   
    private void resetPrefs(SharedPreferences pref) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();      
        editor.putInt(PREF_LIFES, 6);
        editor.putInt(PREF_LEVEL, 0);
        editor.putBoolean(PREF_IS_SET,true);
        editor.commit();
    }

    //to saved the current level and if button continue clicked it will open the latest activity, but i dont know the complete code so i use this

    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

           SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("SavedGame", MODE_PRIVATE); 
           level = pref.getInt("Level", 0); 

           if(level == 0)

            {
                Intent i =new Intent(menu.this, levelone.class);
                startActivity(i);  
            }   
           if(level == 1)

            {
                Intent i =new Intent(menu.this, leveltwo.class);
                startActivity(i);  
            }   
           if(level == 2)

            {
                Intent i =new Intent(menu.this, levelthree.class);
                startActivity(i);  
            }          

               SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
               editor.putInt("Level", level);
               editor.commit();
        }
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }
}
```

in code line of i got 2 error

```
    newgame=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonnewgame);
    newgame.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){

            pref.putInt(PREF_LEVEL,0);    
        }             
      });
```

and this is,
Multiple markers at this line

```
- The method putInt(String, int) is undefined for the type 
 SharedPreferences
- Cannot refer to the non-final local variable pref defined in an 
 enclosing scope
- Line breakpoint:aselectmenu [line: 63] - resetPrefs(SharedPreferences)
```

can anyone help me to fix this code problem?

and how to set continues button when clicked, will continue to latest activity that i had play?

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("SavedGame", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

to this

```
final SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("SavedGame", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Then you will need to access the `SharedPreference.Editor` to actually put the integer you want

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("PrefName", VALUE).commit();
```